# Problema con el logout en Springboot

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, spring-security

Estoy haciendo mi aplicacion con Angular y Springboot.Donde mi objetivo con este post es encontrar la solicion a mi error en mi cerrar sesion.
El problema que me muestra en la consola es el siguiente:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/logout'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Este es mi  SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                        req.requestMatchers("**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), MANAGER.name())
                                .requestMatchers(GET, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_READ.name(), MANAGER_READ.name())
                                .requestMatchers(POST, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_CREATE.name(), MANAGER_CREATE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(PUT, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_UPDATE.name(), MANAGER_UPDATE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(DELETE, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_DELETE.name(), MANAGER_DELETE.name())
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext())
                )
        ;

        return http.build();
    }



}
```

Y en la parte del frontend tengo el siguiente servicio :

```
public logout():Observable<void>{
    return this.httpClient.get<void>(this.authURL + 'logout');
  }
```

Y el void es :

```
cerrarSesion(): void {
    this.authService.logout().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.toastr.success('Sesión cerrada exitosamente', 'Éxito');
      },
      error => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.toastr.warning('No se pudo cerrar sesión. Sesión ya cerrada o no autorizada.', 'Advertencia');
        } else {
          this.toastr.error('Ha ocurrido un error al cerrar sesión', 'Error');
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Gracias de antemano queda abierto a criticas y consejos

Comment: Probe de utilizar en mi controller esta funcion pero no dio resultado: @GetMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<String> logOut(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication
    ) throws IOException {
        logOutService.logout(request, response, authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Session cerrada con éxito");
    }